# How to round datetime64 values

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a numpy array of `datetime64`, and I would like to round off the sub-second values of the array elements. E.g., from `2001-1-1 10:33:32.5` to `2001-1-1 10:33:32.0`. I am looking for a vecotrized method.

More generally, I am looking for a vectorized method to round to any frequency (minutes, days, etc.).

Comment: You don't describe rounding, you describe truncation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rounded = numpy.array(myarray, dtype='datetime64[s]')` or
`rounded = myarray.astype('datetime64[s]')`

This also works for minutes by using:

```
rounded = numpy.array(myarray, dtype='datetime64[m]')
```

Comment: Note:  this *truncates* the milliseconds.  To *round*, one would have to add `numpy.timedelta64(500, 'ms')` before applying either method.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to handle the truncation would be:

```
rounded = numpy.array((numpy.array(myarray, dtype='datetime64[m]'), dtype='datetime64[ms]')
```